# Where are documents about all US military bases and their locations kept?

Tags: military

First of all, I don't know where to post this question, I am asking about the "real" world.

How would someone locate all military bases and facilities in a country, especially the US? For example, in a doomsday scenario [zombies, alien invasion, nuclear fallout...]

From training bases, to weapons depots, to top-secret bases, to missile silos and other military facilities. So Wikipedia is not a good source. [Top secret, national security...]

The military documents everything, but where would they keep these and other very important documents? (For example: nuclear weapons, ballistic missiles, other expensive weapons, R&D labs, all the good stuff.)

The White House? The Pentagon?

For example: in *Metro 2033*, to find a secret facility called D6, you have get a document containing its location from a library (Russian State Library). I am pretty sure that they don't keep secret documents in libraries.

Comment: I'm sure the Russians have a good idea where they all are...

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Your profile states you are Iranian. We are already on the books of several 3 letters agencies for giving instructions on how to make bombs, flood the Netherlands, steal nukes and cook dinosaurs. Helping an enemy country (enemy in the eye of USA administration) finding the location of all the bases was probably missing. Jokes apart, more than the location, what is secret is what they do in each base.

Comment: Since this is a Real World question, I do not see the application to Worldbuilding. This seems like another reference-desk question. I can see Worldbuilding application to a question like "How could I hide my secret military bases" or "How would I organize my military" or "What kinds of foreign influence activities would I want to keep secret"

Comment: Google, so that Google maps can blur out the satellite image.

Comment: In real life, such documents are kept in document storage facilities appropriate for the level of classification. Those facilities may be filing cabinets, documentation rooms, computer systems and so on; only those people who have a real need to know the details will have access to those facilities. Since military bases are *biggg* things and cannot really be hidden, most usually they will have a decoy public identity, i.e., an inocuous indicative and possibly a fake description, accessible and known by the public; this is used for mundane purposes such as food delivery and trash collection.

Comment: For story purposes, why don't you simply *buy* the list from a foreign state?

Answer (score 1):

## There may not be a single location for all files.

Details of the regular bases will be kept in many different places. The department of defense (e.g. the Pentagon), branch headquarters, the department of finance (they paid for it ...), the parliamentary records (the authorized the payment), and many others. There may be some attempts to keep the bases secret from the general public by not including them in civilian maps. This happened not just in the Warsaw Pact but also in NATO countries.

Slightly more secretive places might be officially acknowledged as military installations, but what exactly happens there remains secret. So a civilian searcher might know about thousands of places, with fences and possibly armed guards, and there would be no way to know *which* one is the secret they seek. It could be that the clerks in the department of defense who *usually* handle real estate only know "[No Such Agency](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoSuchAgency) works there, don't ask, send all bills to department X for checking."

And then there could be really "black" sites. Their details might be on file in some military intelligence department, or even only on the base itself.

Regarding going to a public library, this might be the only *surviving, accessible* source of the information. It is quite difficult to make a facility disappear completely. What if the department of transportation wants to build a bypass road over it because it is just "some public land, no special significance?"

The Soviets used to have [closed cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_city) known only by their post box, so going to the postal administration might be another good lead.